# Build time trend for specific stage?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there any way to get the build time trend for one specific step in Jenkins?

I recently tried a change to improve performance of builds within a single step and I wanted an isolated trend of that step. The "Build time trend" shows a trend of the complete build but that includes a lot of other variables that can affect the build times.